# Access VBA - Method or data member no found

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to export some pictures that are embedded as attachments in access through VBA code. For some reason I keep getting a Compile error: Method or data member no found on the `.SaveToFile` part.

```
   Private Sub btnExport_Click()
'  Instantiate the parent recordset.

Dim rsPicture As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPicture = New ADODB.Recordset

rsPicture.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

rsPicture.Open "Select * from Pictures"

rsPicture.MoveFirst

 '  Set rsPicture = db.OpenRecordset("Pictures")


   ' Instantiate the child recordset.
   Set rsPicture = rsPictureTable.Fields("Picture").Value

   '  Loop through the attachments.
   While Not rsPicture.EOF

      '  Save current attachment
      rsPicture.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile _
                  "C:\Pics"
      rsPicture.MoveNext
   Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: make sure if you're going to a newline with code after `.SaveToFile` you put an `& _`, not just the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

The attachments are in a `Recordset2` object (and a `Field2`):

```
Set rsPicture = New ADODB.Recordset2
```

As the error message says, in effect, a `Field` object doesn't have a `SaveToFile` method, a `Field2` object does.

There is a fuller example than the one found in the Help system [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191852.aspx).